# PHP unlink function and cron job

Tags: php, cron, unlink

I am using cron job to execute a php file for sending messages. At the end of my php file that is going to be ran by cron job command, I am going to add `unlink(__FILE__);`.

Does this unlink function remove the current file after sending all messages?

I am not sure that's why I am asking, because sending messages will need some time and I want my file to be deleted after sending all messages and not in the middle of it.

Second; what's happen if there is an error for sending messages?
How can I be informed if there was any error?
Because the function has deleted the php file already!
How can I find out about the errors if there is any?

Comment: What on earth makes you care about the errors if you're unlinking the file? It's like exterminating a population and then caring about their demographic statistics. There's no point error recording a file that no longer will exist. Don't delete the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the way to go. Creating functionality based on removing source code is a road you do not want to follow. One mess up and another file might get deleted, one without a backup (but we all have backups, right? ;) )

Instead, I suggest you simply update your database. You have your messages stored. After each message is send, you update the database and set `sent=1`. Next time you run this script, it should ignore all where `sent=1` and now you don't send duplicates.
You can now also, per message, check if there was a error and log it. And if everything went right, you can also update the DB to when the message was sent.

---

*To answer the actual question: Yes it should. It is probally a timing or a coding error. Which is hard to debug, as the file deletes itself ;)*

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you send those messages but if your script is using a synchronous way (like an SMTP server) to do it, as your script is executed sequentially, the `unlink()` call will be made after every time.

For the error handling, I would suggest you to log them into a file or a database. You can use widespread libraries like [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) to do it easily.